# Google fitness sensors: onDataPoint not being called

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm creating an app that tracks a user's steps using the google fit API. I've been stuck on getting the `onDataPoint` method to be called more than once. My code is almost the exact copy of the google-fit sample code, except with location replaced by steps.

The sample code is [found here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicSensorsApi/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basicsensorsapi/MainActivity.java). It's very similar to the code I am testing out with, with a small adjustment.

Here is my code. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I looked all over and couldn't find a solution.

```
private void findFitnessDataSources() {
    // [START find_data_sources]
    // Note: Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources() requires the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            // At least one datatype must be specified.
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            // Can specify whether data type is raw or derived.
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                        //Let's register a listener to receive Activity data!
                        if (dataSource.getDataType().equals(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                                && mListener == null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Data source for LOCATION_SAMPLE found!  Registering.");
                            registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource,
                                    DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}


private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {
    // [START register_data_listener]
    mListener = new OnDataPointListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
            for (Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
                Value val = dataPoint.getValue(field);
                Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint field: " + field.getName());
                Log.i(TAG, "Detected DataPoint value: " + val);
            }
        }
    };

    Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
            mClient,
            new SensorRequest.Builder()
                    .setDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                    .setDataType(dataType) // Can't be omitted.
                    .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build(),
            mListener)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered.");
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out the `.setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)`. I don't think the default `STEP_COUNT_DELTA` `DataSource` is a raw sensor type. I don't really have easy code to put this in right now, so let me know if that's the issue or not.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was solved in a [later SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38835281/5960850) and my suspicion was correct. The issue is that `TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA` is not a raw data type—[Google uses a combination of sensors, accelerometer, machine learning, etc. to determine step count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30063262/5960850). So the `.setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)` line needs to be removed.

In fact, the OP of the other question noticed that just removing the line gives less accurate results than replacing it with `DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED`, so that is advised.

Comment: onData Point is called only once when 0.Why?

Comment: Hm, you're saying it's still only called once and the value is 0? And you're moving around, right?

Comment: Please suggest me any way to implement step counting. I am new to this.

Answer (score 1):

As i mentioned in my post that step_count of google fit uses derived datatype for everything whether It is cumulative,delta etc.
I observed the results of my app for 10 iteration.
I found that

- Google fit API which is provided by google only uses derived datatype for 
  all step_count.
- You can also not specify the datatype ,but it can give variation in result when compared with Google Fit app.

The same thing is mentioned in Google Fit faq section.
[https://developers.google.com/fit/faq