# Google fit API, onDatapoint method is not being invoked

Tags: google-fit

I am not able to get step count. I've been stuck on getting the `onDataPoint` method to be called. This code is almost correct. I am not able to find why it is not showing step count.

```
package com.example.akkisocc.heath;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataPoint;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataSource;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.DataType;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Field;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.data.Value;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataSourcesRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.OnDataPointListener;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.SensorRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.fitness.result.DataSourcesResult;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnDataPointListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_OAUTH = 1;
    private static final String AUTH_PENDING = "auth_state_pending";
    TextView msg;
    private boolean authInProgress = false;
    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
        msg.setText("On Create");
Log.e("GoogleFit", "Oncreate");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            authInProgress = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
        }

        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ_WRITE))
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OAUTH) {
            authInProgress = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (!mApiClient.isConnecting() && !mApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Log.e("GoogleFit", "RESULT_CANCELED");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("GoogleFit", "requestCode NOT request_oauth");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        DataSourcesRequest dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
                .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                .build();

        ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> dataSourcesResultCallback = new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                    if (DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE.equals(dataSource.getDataType())) {
                        registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mApiClient, dataSourceRequest)
                .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        if (!authInProgress) {
            try {
                authInProgress = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            }
        } else {
            Log.e("GoogleFit", "authInProgress");
        }

    }

    private void registerFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType) {

        SensorRequest request = new SensorRequest.Builder()
                .setDataSource(dataSource)
                .setDataType(dataType)
                .setSamplingRate(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mApiClient, request, this)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        if (status.isSuccess()) {
                            Log.e("GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
        for (final Field field : dataPoint.getDataType().getFields()) {
            final Value value = dataPoint.getValue(field);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field: " + field.getName() + " Value: " + value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I said this in the [google-fit question right before you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799685/google-fitness-sensors-ondatapoint-not-being-called), but did you already try removing `.setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)`? I don't think step count is a raw data type.

Comment: If that's not the issue, please slim down your code to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show what you've tried and narrowed the problem down to. You can't expect someone to debug your entire code from scratch.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matthew,I am now able to run the app perfectly.I noticed that commenting raw data however sometimes gives inaccurate value.Changing the data type from raw to derived is working nicely.

Comment: Cool! Glad to hear. I actually noticed that I don't think `DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE` isn't a real data type. Is that a mistake?

Comment: As mentioned in google fit faq ,step_count should be of derived data type.Thanks,You have been a great help.It was after your point I understood the origin of the problem.

Comment: Care to provide a link to the FAQ you're referring to? We can put that in the answer for others to see

Comment: https://developers.google.com/fit/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As solved in the comments) The issue is that `TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE` is not a raw data type—[Google uses a combination of sensors, accelerometer, machine learning, etc. to determine step count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30063262/5960850). So the `.setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)` line needs to be removed.

OP noticed that just removing the line gives less accurate results than replacing it with `DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED`.

Also, the [Google Fit FAQ](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq) has an example which uses `TYPE_DERIVED`.